# Click on a cell from a large table and insert that cell's contents into a form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with a number of user-fillable fields.  The user needs to enter a number in those fields that is selected from a pop-up window containing a large table of data.

For example, one field might say "Tax rate."  The user would (preferably) click on the (empty) "tax rate" input field, which would bring up the large table of data.  The user would (preferably) click on one of the values in that table which would then close the table and populate the input field with the value.

What I'm hoping (reaaallllyy hoping) is that I don't have to create some sort of special id for each cell in the table in order to pass the number back to the form field, because the tables are huge, and I hope to create them in plain old `<tr><td>1.234</td></tr>` format.

I smell jQuery but I'm not familiar with exactly how to implement it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very rudimentary demo using jQueryUI dialog that might get you started:

HTML:

```html
Rate:<input type="text" id="rate_input" />
<div id="dialog" title="Click a value to fill input and close dialog">
    <table id="rates" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Value 1</td>
            <td>Value 2</td>
            <td>Value 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){    
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400
    });

    $('#rate_input').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });

    $('#rates td').click(function () {
        $('#rate_input').val($(this).text());
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5jMqJ/

Comment: Wow. That's killer.  Thank you!  I wish I could buy you a beer.